# How to change ios statusbar color in xamarin forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin, statusbar

I am working with xamarin forms and I am facing a problem cause my top bar is black and the status bar letters is black as well...then, it's difficult to write...
Is there a way to change this color?
And how about the color of the toolbar items (which are blue per default)?

Comment: The status bar and toolbar items have nothing to do with each other. Please decide what one question you want to ask, and ask it.

Comment: Indeed you have a status bar where you have the time, carrier etc and the navigation bat where you have your toolbar items. As this is not a direct answer i am inviting you to play inside your iOS project in the AppDelegate.cs file, inside the FinishedLaunching func, with the following:

Comment: UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, true);

            UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = 

            UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor =

            UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
            {
                TextColor = 

            });